# Split a List of structs into sublists based on the stucts contents

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List that I need to split into sublists, one for each value of MyStruct.GroupingString.  Can I do this via linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
somelist.ToLookup(x => x.GroupingString)
```

Comment: How do I get a List/Array's out of the Grouping that generates?

Comment: @Dan Neely: You can either iterate and use the `Key` property, or do a direct lookup using the indexer (think it uses a backing Dictionary). If you dont need the key, I would probably go with Mehrdad Afshari suggestion.

Comment: Am I missing something?  This crashes when I try to iterate the results and cast them back into a list:

foreach (List<MyStruct> foo in someList.ToLookup(x => x.ident))

Comment: @Dan Neely: `IEnumerable<MyStruct>`

Answer (score 3):

```
List<List<StructType>> groupings = list.GroupBy(x => x.GroupingString)
                                       .Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: @leppie: why? Isn't this what the OP says he wants? :-?

Comment: I'd probably skip the entire second line (keep it as an IEnumerable of IGroupings), but this IS specifically what he asked for. :)

Comment: It is correct, but `ToLookup` just does it so much nicer :)  OTOH, yours will generate more efficient Linq2SQL.  :)